# Celery concurrency

Tags: python-3.x, django-celery, celery-task

I have a celery task that needs to be sequential, i.e the messages need to be evaluated one by one. For this, I have used the concurrency=1 option in the worker startup. But the issue is that the tasks are slower than I require them to be.

Probably a stupid question but is there any way to allocate more CPU resources to one concurrent process for a celery worker or is that a hardware limitation?